# Jquery Trigger call function multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this below function to delete the item from the list jquery ajax call. Now I want to reload the items so that I have using the trigger function.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "FamilyManagerService.asmx/DeleteFreePurchasedFamily",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'FamilyId':'" + idFreeFamily + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
            }
        }).done(function () {
            if ($(".categoryList .activeFolder").length) {
                $.session.set("CategoryName", $(".categoryList .activeFolder").attr('id'));
                $.session.set("CategorynameView", $(".categoryList .activeFolder").text());
                $(".categoryList a").trigger("click");
            }
        });
```

Note: 
1. Trigger Event fires all anchor link within this ´.categoryList a´ selector.
2. I want to fire that event only once.

Tried by including stopPropagation, stopImmediatePropagation, PreventDefault but it will fire multiple times.

```
$('.categoryList a').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FamilyManagerService.asmx/getPurchasedParameterType",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'categoryName':'" + categoryName + "', 'IsFreeFamily':'" + true + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
            //TODO:
        }
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Please suggest how I can call the event to fire only once.

Comment: Your selector `.categoryList a` **tells** it to fire all links

Comment: What is the context of first ajax request? Why trigger an event, why not calling the handler if a referenced function is used?

Comment: You want to execute it once? Or once per element?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I want to execute it once.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown how can i call the event to fire only once ?

Comment: "call the event to fire only once" usually that's mean using ".one()" but i'm quite sure this is not what you are looking for, once term is ambiguous. I guess you want to trigger click event for only one element. If it's that then specify your first ajax context, HOW do you call it???

Comment: You can use a global scoped variable, a cookie, the local storage, add a class to the body, and so on to store the execution of the function anche than check its value

Comment: @A.Wolff Did you mean to call trigger click event for only one element as ".categoryList a #id" ?

Answer (score 1):

As DontVoteMeDown noted in the comments, if you have several elements in your HTML that correspond to `.categoryList a` then JQuery will trigger a click event on **every** element, and your function will be called several times.

You could try to be more specific in your JQuery selector when triggering the click. (Add a class or an ID to make sure only one link matches your selector).

**OR (and probably a better solution)**

Maybe your "triggering a click" approach is not appropriate. Just make the new call, by calling a function (similar to your click callback), without clicking.

```
var reloadItems = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FamilyManagerService.asmx/getPurchasedParameterType",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'categoryName':'" + categoryName + "', 'IsFreeFamily':'" + true + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
            //TODO:
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FamilyManagerService.asmx/DeleteFreePurchasedFamily",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'FamilyId':'" + idFreeFamily + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    }).done(function () {
        if ($(".categoryList .activeFolder").length) {
            $.session.set("CategoryName", $(".categoryList .activeFolder").attr('id'));
            $.session.set("CategorynameView", $(".categoryList .activeFolder").text());
            reloadItems();
        }
    });
```

which also simplifies your event handling (as A. Wolff commented):

```
$('.categoryList a').click(reloadItems);
```

Comment: even when u give class or id and trigger , it will be fired in a recursive manner, as the click function will be called recursively from with in

Comment: The click callback doesn't seem recursive to me. Am I missing something ? please explain :)

Comment: even if u give class to the link , the clicked element is one in this list of .categoryList a, so the function again starts going on recursively

Comment: the click function is again called in the success function ,so it ll be recursive+

Comment: in onclick handler, this is not the same ajax request than the one which trigger click event. That's why i asked OP context of first ajax request and he is still unable to answer it...

Comment: The click function is called in the `done()` of the delete call, and the click calls the refresh (another call). I don't think it's recursive.

Comment: Usinf referenced function as handler seems the easiest way to fix issue, no need to trigger anything +1  BTW: `$('.categoryList a').click(reloadItems)`

Comment: Indeed, adding it in the answer